# Put thousand separator using REGEX replace method

Tags: regex

I have to put thousand separator between numbers. I have done till now:

**Input string**

```
1852  
2589653  
586699  
8542.28
```

**The find pattern**

```
(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

**replace-with**

```
,
```

**result**

```
1,852  
2,589,653  
586,699  
8,542.28
```

---

**TODO**
I want to eliminate all year ranges from 1700 to 2010, from match-collection.

Anyone have any idea. All suggestions are welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, first match the 1700-2010 range, then negate that and add it to the pattern you have

Comment: It is not a big task to create a pattern to match ranges between 1700 to 2010, but problem is how to merge two patterns afterward.

Comment: This will put thousands separators in digits *after* the decimal point, too. Is that intended?

Comment: Separator should be placed before decimal point.

Comment: Changing your regex to `(?<!\..*)(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))` helps in not putting thousands separators after the decimal point. But it requires that the regex engine supports arbitrary-length lookbehind (.NET does, but nearly no one else).

Comment: It's really works like charm, just after a more minor modification to your code ``(?<!\.\d*)(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))``, as **«.»** going to match all chars except newline for this context, as no flags been specified.

Comment: I test (?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)) in java which has the same function as  (?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good way to use regular expressions.

Instead, use the string formatting features of your language:

- Use a simple regular expression to find the numbers, if you have to extract them from text.
- Convert them to floating point or integer numbers (as appropriate)
- Use a string format specifier to say you would like them output with a thousands separator.

For example, here's a shell transcript where I extract a number from a string and format it with a comma thousands separator: (Python 2.x)

```
In [12]: import re

In [13]: number_pattern = re.compile(r"\d+(.\d+)") #positive integer or floating point number

In [14]: mystring = "The size of the rocket is 3141592.6."

In [15]: number_string = number_pattern.search(mystring).group() #extract the number as a string

In [16]: number_string
Out[16]: '3141592.6'

In [18]: number = float(number_string) #convert to number

In [19]: '{:,}'.format(number) #format with thousands separator
Out[19]: '3,141,592.6'
```

Doing it this way also makes eliminating ranges of numbers trivial.

```
if (number > 1700) or (number < 2100):
    pass #do something
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Alternatives are always there in any situations. But, I accept Joey's solution as it matches my requirement, as I am going to use it in my VB.NET app. And that pattern works fine.

Comment: Does the regex work as expected? (it matches `1a3` but not `13`) Shouldn't it be `r"\d+(\.\d+)?"`?

Comment: I like this approach, but need to match a different numeric pattern. The haven't been able to crack a regex pattern match spaces as thousands separators. e.g. 400 or 40 000 or 40 000 000 or 4 000 000 000. Any ideas?

Comment: @tahoar: Don't piggyback off existing questions - ask a new question instead.

Comment: This is pretty Python related. What could the `.format` equivalent be?

Comment: With f-strings, if `number` variable holds your float, `f'{number:,}'`

Comment: It's not that hard to solve it by RegEx - see blow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a RegEx Example in PowerShell:

```
[Regex]::Replace(12345, '[0-9](?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))', '$0''')
12'345
```